# JVM running on IDE takes more processing power than running on command line

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jvm, executable-jar

I faced a very frustrating issue. I used an IDE to develop my application. I was monitoring performance through the execution times in IDE but unfortunately when I exported my classes to Jar files, it ran  7x slower on command line. I checked my JVM and made sure the same JVMs are linked to both executions. Allocated more heap memory to the commandline.

Later, I used a process performance monitoring tool and ran both applications (on CMD & on IDE) simultaneously. I noticed that both processes are identical on everything but for CPU power. The process running on IDE takes around 19%-23% of CPU usage while this on CMD took about 6%-11% CPU usage. This may explain why the run on IDE takes less time.

In order to make the application clear, below is the piece of code that taking most of the time

```
                         for (Call call: calls {

                            CallXCD callXCD = call.getCallXCD();    
                            if(callXCD.isOnNet()){
                                System.out.println("OnNet");
                            }
                            else if (callXCD.isXNet()){
                                System.out.println("XNet");

                            }
                            else if (callXCD.isOthers()){
                                System.out.println("Others");

                            }
                            else if (callXCD.isIntra()){
                                System.out.println("Intra");
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Not Known");
                            }
                         }
```

CallXCD is an object containing several string variables and several methods like isOnNet and isXNet. These methods apply the compareTo() method on the strings of the object and return true or false according to this comparison.

I profiled this piece of code by printing the time each iteration take. In the IDE each iteration took about 0.007 milli second while in command line running the jar file, it took about 0.2 milli second. Because my code takes around 4 million iteration on this, the negative impact on performance is very significant

Why does this happen?. Is there any way to allocate more processing power to JVM like memory arguments.

[image: IDE on Right - CMD on Left]

Comment: In the IDE, are you debugging? What does your application *do*? Note that the IO traces are *radically* different between the two, so I'm not sure where you get the idea that the processes are "identical on everything but for CPU power".

Comment: Hello Jon, same behavior happened even when I remove all System.out.print. To make it more clear regarding the performance thing. I profiled certain method that is being looped for 4 million times. The method takes an average of 0.007 ms to execute on IDE while it takes 0.2 ms to execute on command line

Comment: Well is there *any* output? We're really operating in the blind as to what your code is doing. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: @Jon, I edited my post to include the piece causing the issue. Currently I don't make any output but printing time taken. Even when I remove printing time, nothing changed on my stop watch. I don't think it is the printing thing. Do you think there is a reason behind the processing power difference in the snapshot??

Comment: You don't *think* it's the printing - but given that the output on a command line is very different from in an IDE, you should validate it. In general, including unnecessary IO in the benchmark time is a really bad idea. I suggest you get rid of the System.out calls for all but the top-most result (i.e. just write the overall result once, after you've finished timing).

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Thank you very much. I removed every single Print and the time on CMD was reduced significantly. I am ashamed I insisted, it has nothing to do with printing. I would be grateful, if you write your proposal as an answer to accept and upvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(After a conversation in comments.)

It seems this is down to a difference in how console output is handled in your command line and in your IDE. These can behave very significantly differently in terms of auto-scrolling, size of buffer etc.

Generally, when benchmarking code it's good to isolate the code you're actually interested in away from any diagnostic output which can interfere with the results. If you absolutely *have* to include diagnostic output, writing it to a file (possibly on a ram disk) can help to reduce the differences between console implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your IDE has different JVM options, for running your process? Larger heap size (-Xmx) could reduce garbage collection costs. If your application is memory-intensive & choking on an insufficent heap size, this could easily be the problem.

The IDE typically also pipes your process's standard input/ output. I don't know if that would be *more efficient* than standard output to console, but if you're printing/logging a lot it might be a factor to consider.

As Jon Skeet says, there's a big apparent difference between the I/O traces on left & right.

The third main thing an IDE does, in Debug mode, is attach to your process as a debugger. But this normally makes the process slower, not faster.

Summary: best check your IDE's JVM options & launch configuration. Maybe it's run with *different parameters*, in a different *working directory*, or with too small a *heap size*.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such effects when the IDE (eclipse) used a newer Java version than is used when starting from the command line. Also, it could be that when running from within eclipse you are using the server VM and on the command line the client JVM is used. This can either be set in the run configuration or in the wirkspace JVM settings ("Default VM arguments" when you click on "Edit JRE" in the "Installed JREs" preference page).

So, first make sure the same arguments are used. Add the arguments that are used when starting from within eclipse to your command line.

Comment: May you please help me how can I extract the exact arguments from eclipse. I navigated to Run>Run Configurations> arguments and found no arguments at all